# What is the recommended way to remove data type descriptors from a DynamoDB response?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB includes a data type descriptor for each element in query response, as shown below:

```
"Item": { 
    "M" : {
        "Age": {"N": "8"},
        "Name": {"S": "Fido"},
        "Vaccinations": {
            "M": {
                "Rabies": {
                    "L": [
                        {"S": "2009-03-17"},
                        {"S": "2011-09-21"},
                        {"S": "2014-07-08"}
                    ]
                },
                "Distemper": {"S": "2015-10-13"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to strip all of these descriptors ("S", "L", "M", etc), so that it looks like the next example, before I `JSON.stringify` the data.

```
"Item": {
    "Age": "8",
    "Name": "Fido",
    "Vaccinations": {
        "Rabies": [
            "2009-03-17",
            "2011-09-21",
            "2014-07-08"
         ]
         "Distemper": "2015-10-13"
     }
}
```

Is there are standard (or recommended) method for doing this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They have a converter that you can use.

For instance, here is their example:

```
var data= {"Item": {
    "Age": {"N": "8"},
    "Name": {"S": "Fido"},
    "Vaccinations": {
        "M": {
            "Rabies": {
                "L": [
                    {"S": "2009-03-17"},
                    {"S": "2011-09-21"},
                    {"S": "2014-07-08"}
                ]
            },
            "Distemper": {"S": "2015-10-13"}
        }
}}};
var marshalled = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(data);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html

Answer (score 6):

Use the DynamoDB DocumentClient, it will do it for you.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html

Comment: as the OP mentioned he is using query function to retrieve results and event after reading the docs, nothing can change the fact that these results will come with datatypes along.

Comment: The DocumentClient returns "normal" looking JS objects (without the type descriptors) as results to all its methods: scan, get, query, etc.

Comment: That's not true, it actually depends on how you build your query, scan etc. For example if you use attributes with ":createdAt": {S: "02/09/2019"} the results will always return their datatypes, otherwise  if you use ":createdAt": "02/09/2019" the results will be without datatypes. I think it would be better to answer the OP question if he'd showed how the query, get was built.

Answer (score 5):

Not familiar with working with DynamoDb. My guess is there are SDK's you can use to do this for you, or settings in queries that can be used to turn off the descriptors

Following seems to work for all the cases in your sample

```js
var descriptors = ['L', 'M', 'N', 'S'];

function flatten(o) {

  // flattens single property objects that have descriptors  
  for (let d of descriptors) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
      return o[d];
    }
  }

  Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {

    for (let d of descriptors) {
      if (o[k].hasOwnProperty(d)) {
        o[k] = o[k][d];
      }
    }
    if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
      o[k] = o[k].map(e => flatten(e))
    } else if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
      o[k] = flatten(o[k])
    }
  });

  return o;
}

data = flatten(data)
console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var data = {"Item":{"Age":{"N":"8"},"Name":{"S":"Fido"},"Vaccinations":{"M":{"Rabies":{"L":[{"S":"2009-03-17"},{"S":"2011-09-21"},{"S":"2014-07-08"}]},"Distemper":{"S":"2015-10-13"}}}}};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @charlietfl.  Your answer looks good for all the cases that I will need to deal with.  I did look further into the AWS documentation for high-level interface SDKs for DynamoDB - there seems to be SDKs for Java and .Net, but not javascript.  There might be third-party SDKs, but your proposal looks quick and effective for what I need.

Comment: Only thing I wonder is if you can get 2 descriptors in one object at same level. If so this will go south on you

Comment: I have accepted this answer as it directly addresses the question that I posed.  However, I have actually changed my code to use document Client from the AWS Javascript SDK, as suggested by@bwinant. I _think_ that there should be just one descriptor at each level, but I could be proven wrong about this.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this:

```js
var data= {"Item": {
    "Age": {"N": "8"},
    "Name": {"S": "Fido"},
    "Vaccinations": {
        "M": {
            "Rabies": {
                "L": [
                    {"S": "2009-03-17"},
                    {"S": "2011-09-21"},
                    {"S": "2014-07-08"}
                ]
            },
            "Distemper": {"S": "2015-10-13"}
        }
}}};

var keys_black_list=['N', 'S', 'M', 'L'];

function correct_data(_data){
  var new_data={};
  for(var key in _data){
    if (typeof _data[key] === 'object') {
        for(var bl_key in keys_black_list){
           if(_data[key][keys_black_list[bl_key]]){

             if(typeof _data[key][keys_black_list[bl_key]] === 'object'){
              new_data[key]=correct_data(_data[key][keys_black_list[bl_key]]);
             }else{
              new_data[key]=_data[key][keys_black_list[bl_key]];
             }
           }
        }
    }
  }
  return new_data;
}


console.log(correct_data(data.Item));
```

Answer (score 3):

With sdk version 3 there are a marshall and unmarshall utilities

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html

```
import { marshall, unmarshall } from '@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb';

try {
  const data = await ddbClient.send(new GetItemCommand(configReadService.params));
  return unmarshall(data.Item) as unknown as ConfigAssets;
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Reading the configuration database failed ', e)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

before sending final response call this function.

```
function parseDynamoDBItem(
item: Record<string, DynamoDBItem>
): Record<string, any> {
 const result: Record<string, any> = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
const value = item[key];
if (value.S) {
  result[key] = value.S;
} else if (value.N) {
  result[key] = Number(value.N);
} else if (value.L) {
  result[key] = value.L.map((item: any) => parseDynamoDBItem(item));
} else if (value.M) {
  result[key] = parseDynamoDBItem(value.M);
}
}
return result;
}
```

calling above function.

```
 const bookmarks = await getBookmarkDetailsForUser(userId);

  const bookmarksWithoutDataTypes = bookmarks.map((bookmark) =>
    parseDynamoDBItem(bookmark)
  );
  const response = JSON.stringify(bookmarksWithoutDataTypes);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: response,
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

By using the DynamoDB DocumentClient, as suggested by @bwinant, the type descriptors can be avoided altogether.

The example below uses docClient get() and put() within a http request handler:

```
// handleHttpRequest is the entry point for Lambda requests
exports.handleHttpRequest = function(request, context, done) {
  try {
    const id = request.pathParameters.id;
    let response = {
      headers: {},
      body: '',
      statusCode: 200
    };

    switch (request.httpMethod) {
      case 'GET': {
        let dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB();
        var params = {
          TableName: myTable,
          Key: { 'id' : id },
        };

        docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            throw `Dynamo Get Error (${err})`
          } else {
            response.body = JSON.stringify(data.Item);
            done(null, response);          
          }
        });
        break;
      }

      case 'POST': {
        let myData = JSON.parse(request.body || '{}');
        let params = {
          TableName: myTable,
          Item: {
            id : id,
            my_data : myData
          }
        }
        docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            throw `Dynamo Put Error (${err})`;
          } else {
            done(null, data);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    done(e, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP question was very clear, he is using a query function and its different than get or put functions, get will get you a single item, not mentioning other differences.